# Azure devops pipline No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix

Tags: android, react-native, azure-devops

Hi I'm trying to build react native android app in azure pipelines but I can't get it to work...
The error I'm keep getting is like this. I tried everything I found on google but nothing helped.

Build task:

```
    - task: Gradle@2
  displayName: "Build APK"
  inputs:
      gradleWrapperFile: "android/gradlew"
      workingDirectory: "android/"
      options: "-PversionName=$(NEW_VERSION) -PversionCode=$(Build.BuildId)"
      tasks: "assembleStage" # assembleRelease or assembleStage
      publishJUnitResults: false
      javaHomeOption: "JDKVersion"
      jdkVersionOption: "1.11"
      gradleOptions: "-Xmx3072m"
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2 (and can't upgrade it)

ERROR:

```
Task :react-native-document-scanner:stripReleaseDebugSymbols FAILED
```

Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.

> Task :app:mergeStageJavaResource
> Task :app:mergeExtDexStage

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':@react-native-document-scanner:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25m 59s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
690 actionable tasks: 690 executed
Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
at ExecState._setResult (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:944:25)
at ExecState.CheckComplete (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:927:18)
at ChildProcess. (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.200.2/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:840:19)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)

I tried specify ndkVersion to "21.4.7075529" didn't help. Also I tried to upgrade gradle version to 4.1.0 but same error came up.

Thanks

Comment: Will this problem occur when you build locally? If it only appears in the devops pipeline, can you compare the difference between the local environment and the devops environment? You can find the Android software version of each agent here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software.

Comment: It only appears in devops pipeline. I think it's because I don't actually have NDK installed on local computer and thats the difference. I manage to fix it eventually by adding bash script before build: echo "ndk.dir=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" >> local.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding bash script as step like this:

echo "ndk.dir=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" >> local.properties